# .length property undefined error

Tags: javascript

I have to create a function to show the number of characters typed in the textarea. I think the code is ok, but I get an undefined error. Can you tell me why? Thanks.

```html
<html>

<head>
  <style>
    textarea {
      width: 200px;
      height: 130px
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <textarea onkeypress="caractere()" name="numar"></textarea>
  <p>Number of characters typed: <span></span></p>

  <script>
    function caractere() {
      document.getElementsByTagName('span')[0].innerHTML = document.getElementsByName('numar')[0].length;
    }
  </script>
```

Comment: Use `value` i.e. `document.getElementsByTagName('span')[0].innerHTML = document.getElementsByName('numar')[0].value.length;`

Answer (score 0):

> document.getElementsByName('numar')[0].length

`getElementsByName` returns an HTMLCollection. When you select `[0]`, you're selecting the first element in the collection. HTML elements do not have a `length` property. You need to get the length of the *value* of the element:

```html
<html>

<head>
  <style>
    textarea {
      width: 200px;
      height: 130px
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <textarea onkeypress="caractere()" name="numar"></textarea>
  <p>Number of characters typed: <span></span></p>

  <script>
    function caractere() {
      document.getElementsByTagName('span')[0].innerHTML = document.getElementsByName('numar')[0].value.length;
    }
  </script>
```

But there's not much sense using a method that returns a *collection* when you're only selecting a single element. Use querySelector instead:

```
document.querySelector('span').textContent =
  document.querySelector('[name="numar"]').value.length;
```

Comment: Isn't this should be marked as duplicate?